# Spring Integration "Integration-graph" view for annotation based project

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, integration, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

In Spring Integration is it possible to view "Integration-graph" for annotation based project? 
In XML based project, there is an tab to view "Integration-graph" but in annotation based project how to view the whole project flow in single slide?

Answer (score 0):

No, we don't have that feature implemented in STS. In case you would like to raise this as an enhancement request, please file a ticket here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide